# Error al definir matrices en visual basic

Tags: array, visual-studio, vb.net, array-bidimensional

cuando dimensiono los arreglos dentro del button3 no me da problemas y compila bien, pero cuando intento definir sus valores fuera del button para hacer que las variables sean globales me da error, es al definir sus valores. Necesito que sean globales porque debo usarlas desde otro form y no se a que se debe este error.

```
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Form1.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    txtUsuario.Clear()
    txtContrasena.Clear()
End Sub

Dim registro(4, 1) As String
    registro(0, 0) = "gerente"
    registro(0, 1) = "123"
    registro(1, 0) = "oficinista"
    registro(1, 1) = "1234"
    registro(2, 0) = "recepcionista"
    registro(2, 1) = "12345"

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim encontrada As Boolean = False
    Dim usuarioIntroducido As String = txtUsuario.Text
    Dim contrasenaIntroducida As String = txtContrasena.Text
    Dim verificador As Boolean

    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        If usuarioIntroducido = registro(i, 0) And contrasenaIntroducida = registro(i, 1) Then
            encontrada = True
        ElseIf usuarioIntroducido = registro(i, 0) And contrasenaIntroducida <> registro(i, 1) Then
            verificador = True
        End If
    Next

    If encontrada = True Then
        Me.Hide()
        Form3.Show()
    ElseIf usuarioIntroducido = "" And contrasenaIntroducida = "" Then
        MsgBox("Por favor ingrese usuario y contraseña")
    ElseIf verificador = True Then
        MsgBox("Contraseña incorrecta")
    Else
        MsgBox("Usuario incorrecto")

    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtContrasena.TextChanged
End Sub
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Intenta con `Public` en lugar de `Dim`

Comment: Me salta el mismo error

Comment: Intenta con `Public Static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El orden del codigo es importante...

Vos podes definir la matriz afuera de cualquier metodo, "para hacerla global" (ya te explico porque esto no es cierto), y cargarla en el load de tu form, de forma tal que tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim registro(4, 1) As String

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        registro(0, 0) = "gerente"
        registro(0, 1) = "123"
        registro(1, 0) = "oficinista"
        registro(1, 1) = "1234"
        registro(2, 0) = "recepcionista"
        registro(2, 1) = "12345"
    End Sub
```

Ahora.. una vez solucionado eso, tratemos de entender porque esto no es global, si no solo publico.

Resulta que para usarlo en cualquier lado, tenes que definir un objeto del tipo form2.. por lo tanto, no lo podes usar en cualquier lado, si no en cualquier lado que tenga creado un objeto de ese tipo.

Pero, si esto se va a usar en varios lados, no seria ideal que estuviera en una clase? mas si solo sirve para definir esos valores a mano.